# Load needed content from one file fast and easily?

Tags: c#, windows, io

Imagine there is a game with a lot of content, like car models.
I don't want to have them in the RAM all the time to save memory and want to load them only when needed. This would be easily when having one file per car - but I would have so many files at the end and the project would become hard to share etc.

But when I store everything into one file, I don't know where what is.
Is there a way storing everything into one file and navigate to the content as easily as if I do one file per content entry? Only thing I can imagine is saving the byte positions where something begins in a 2nd file (or as header in the content file) but I'm very unsure about that solution.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to reinvent the wheel here. What exactly are you trying to accomplish that needs that many files?

Comment: why not use a small database?

Comment: I mean you could pack everything into an archive and unpack it when installing or unpack it into a cache when the program runs.

Comment: Use a small data structure such as a hash table or a dictionary so that you can keep track of things. Then you can use serialization to store this object in a text file or (etc..) and then deserialize it and use it whenever needed

Comment: I think you're better off addressing your directory structure. Rather than trying to cram all the data into a single file, I would add depth in the directory structure and do it in such a way that you can easily choose which file to read/write at run time (ie make it so your software can easily create the path dynamically).

Comment: It is not up to you, the file system cache keeps it in RAM anyway.  This is not a problem.

Comment: @HansPassant I believe he means loading and unloading things such as model and texture files for various items in a videogame. Those can be very costly and are distributed across multiple files for that reason rather than all being loaded into RAM at runtime.

Comment: I know, just pointing out that thinking that you can control what's in RAM is a pipe dream.  It is just not the way the operating system works.  You can't keep stuff in RAM, you can't keep it out either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to do it is when you write the file you keep track (in memory) where stuff is. Then, at the end of the file you write an index. So your file looks like this:

```
offset 0: data for object 1
offset 0x0473: data for object 2
offset 0x1034: data for object 3
etc.
```

You can write this file using `BinaryWriter`. Before you write each object, you query `writer.BaseStream.Position` to get the current position of the file. You save that information in memory (just the object name and its position).

When you're done writing all of the objects, you save the current position:

```
indexPosition = writer.BaseStream.Position;
```

Then write the index at the end of the file:

```
name: "object 1", position: 0
name: "object 2", position: 0x0473
etc.
```

Write an empty index entry to signify the end of objects:

```
name: "", position: 0xFFFFFFFF
```

And the last thing you do is write the index position at the end of the file:

```
writer.Write(indexPosition);
```

Now, you can open the file with a `BinaryReader`. Seek to end-of-file minus 8 bytes, read the long integer there. That gives you the position of the index. Seek to the index and start reading index entries forward until you get to one that has a position of 0xFFFFFFFF.

You now have the index in memory. You can create a `Dictionary<string, long>` so that, given an object name, you can find its position in the file. Get the position, seek there, and read the object.

This kind of thing was pretty common when we were writing games in the late '90s. You can still do it, although you're probably better off going with a simple database.

Comment: Did this and works very good :)
I would have ended up with like +2000 files otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few different compression and archiving methods you could use to hold your files if you're looking to store them temporarily in a larger file for transport. Almost any compression method could work, which you choose is entirely up to you.

Example .zip compression can be found here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404280.aspx

There's also the .cab file format that you can easily pack multiple files into and unpack later when you have need for them. There's an interesting article on creating .cab files in C# found here:

http://mnarinsky.blogspot.com/2009/11/creating-cab-file-in-c.html

It does require that you add references to Microsoft.Deployment.Compression.Cab.dll and Microsoft.Deployment.Compression.dll but the code itself is fairly simple after that. If you find none of those to be a suitable answer to your question, my only other suggestion is that you better organize the files rather than cramming them all into a single folder as that can make it quite difficult to navigate.

Also try using a collection to keep track of the file names if that helps too. You could define files in the XML and load everything into a dictionary or hash table if it needs to be more dynamic or define it in the code itself if you prefer that.

EDIT:

You can also try using a third party installer for transport. They offer many functions outside of compressing and packing files and will handle the data compression for you. I prefer NSIS personally as I find it to be highly user friendly but any installer can work. A few example installers are:

Installshield: http://www.installshield.com/ (integrates with Visual Studio)

WIX: http://wix.sourceforge.net/ (also integrates with Visual Studio, good if you're looking for something more XML based)

NSIS: http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page (scriptable, doesn't integrate with Visual Studio, easy guided design with Nsisqssg if you'd prefer not to do the bulk of the scripting on your own)

They all function differently but essentially achieve the same end result. It all depends on exactly what you're looking for.