# store/retrieve certain array from file contains arrays

Tags: c, algorithm, file, io

I have a number of arrays and I want to save them to a file in such a way that
I can retrieve certain array say array 15 without retrieving all the others into memory

I thought to do it as follows:

align their storage on 2K basis inside the file.

-------------------File-----------------------------

Page 0

------------------2K------------------------------------

Page 1

------------------4K-----------------------------------

Page 2

---

for each array I'll store array header structure before saving the array

it'll be

```
typedef struct {
char* arrayNAme;
int   numberOfElements;
int   numberOfPages;
} arrayHeader;
```

for example, if I want to reach array named "required_array"

I'll do (in pseudo code)

```
fp = fread(file);
arrayHeader* ah;
while(!EOF)
{
   ah =  = readHeader(fp, sizeof(arrayHeader));
   if(ah->name == "required_array")
      {
       arr =  loadMyArra(fp,);
       lseek(fp,ah->numberOfPages*2K,SEEK_SET);
       break;
      }

}
```

this approach may work fine but I have a performance problem as I need to lseek to the header of each stored array till I get my required one - O(n) time where n is the number of arrays.

What I'm asking is there any known way of handling such things? or any recommendations on other techniques that could perform better ?

Comment: Why not have a global header with a table of contents, i.e. array names and offsets? You can look up the name in that header and seek to the correct offset directly.

Comment: I thought of that too, but there're 2 things - 1- in my case I save array by array into the file so to collect all header info ill wait until the last array is saved and I think it'll be hard to save it at the start of the file as I dont know pre the total number of arrays to hold the space in the start of the file for it........................ 2. there'll be alittle memory problem as I'll need to load all the headers for the files and search through them for mine

Comment: If you know the number of arrays, you can leave a free block before writing the arrays, write the arrays and collect the offsets as you go. Then rewind and write the data. Alternatively, write the table at the end of the file. That way, the file is even extensible. (PDF files do that.) When you read, seek to just before the end and read the table size, seek backwards to the beginning of the table and read it.

Comment: A description of how I do it, with some small code snippets in C#. An example, with some small code snippets in C#: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17709842/56778

Comment: The structure header has pointer field. For writing these  type of structures to file, it is necessery to change the dynamic pointer to static one with maximum size, or handle writing, feild by field instead of by struct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea from @MOehm is good. You can use it with a small change: save the global index table **at the end of the file**.

This is exactly the scheme the program `zip` uses. It also makes it easy for you to compute this table, because you just have to collect the position of the arrays at the time you write them in the file.

Look at the reference for the ZIP file format to find a (complex) example of this scheme. The structure you're interested in is called: central directory.

**Reference**

- [ZIP file format design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)#Design)